# Should I Use only wpdb Class to Write Custom Queries?

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I have to write many custom queries for my new plugin. I know that I can use [wpdb  Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

But it is really complex for me when I have to write long queres with lots of where closes and join queries using wpdb  Class.

But I can write those queries very easily in normal way. I can **create a new connection** and I can write queries and I can run them using **`mysqli_query`** function.

Is there any problem if I do it as above mentioned method?

Comment: Not sure but, If you will use "`mysqli_query`" function then to make connection you have to specify Database name and that can be problem if you are making a plugin. For e.g. If someone install you plugin then how your plugin will know what is the name of database. In other word you have to find a way to dynamically assign database name and other options also like `hostname` etc, so it will work for everyone. Since `$wpdb` directly target wordpress database, so there is no such kind of problem if you use `$wpdb`.

Comment: Yes, you can use wpdb to write custom queries.
you have to call "global $wpdb;" in respective function.

For reference you can follow wordpress codex::   https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb